# Orchard Contrib.Taxonomies - permalinks in conflict when removing drafts

Tags: orchardcms

Previewing and Rejecting drafts using Contrib.Taxonomies in Orchard:

I have a requirement to preview (and if necessary, reject) taxonomy terms after an import.

I have attempted to do this with the following code:

A. I have changed the last line of the standard Import code to say:

```
Services.ContentManager.Create(term, VersionOptions.Draft);
```

(instead of VersionOptions.Published)

B. My preview screen has a "Publish" button, with a controller action with this code:

```
// remove current published terms
foreach (var term in _taxonomyService.GetTerms(taxonomyId)) {
    _taxonomyService.DeleteTerm(term);
}

// publish draft terms created at import
foreach (var draftTerm in _MyTaxonomyService.GetDraftTerms(taxonomyId)) {
    Services.ContentManager.Publish(draftTerm.As<ContentItem>());
}
```

C. The preview screen also has a "Reject" button, with a controller action with this code:

```
// delete drafts
foreach (var draftTerm in _MyTaxonomyService.GetDraftTerms(taxonomyId)) {
    _taxonomyService.DeleteTerm(draftTerm);
}
```

With the above code, I can "Publish" as many times as I like and it works as expected.

However, if I "Reject" and then Publish I get "Permalinks in conflict" for the top-level term.

How can I remove the drafts without getting a permalinks conflict the next time I publish?

(Also note that removing drafts should not effect permalinks/display aliases of the current published terms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the fundamental problem was that `_taxonomyService.DeleteTerm()` was firing the `AutoRouteHandler.OnRemoved()` event method.

This event method will call down the stack to `AliasStorage.Remove()`, which only takes path/aliassource as arguments, i.e. it will remove ALL AliasRecords that match the given path, i.e. aliases which the published version is still dependent on!

My solution to this problem was to replace the `_taxonomyService.DeleteTerm()` call with my own custom method `_MyTaxonomyService.DeleteDraftTerm()` for deleting draft terms. Note the removal of the AutoRoutePartHandler from the handler event calls:

```
    public void DeleteDraftTerm(ContentItem contentItem)
    {
        var draftVersions = _contentItemVersionRepository.Fetch(x => x.ContentItemRecord == contentItem.Record && x.Latest && !x.Published);
        var context = new RemoveContentContext(contentItem);

        _handlers.Value.Invoke(handler => handler.Removing(context), Logger);

        foreach (var version in draftVersions)
        {
            if (version.Latest)
            {
                version.Latest = false;
            }
        }

       // comment this line out and replace with lines below
       // _handlers.Value.Invoke(handler => handler.Removed(context), Logger);

       var handlersExceptAutoRoute = _handlers.Value.Where(x => x.GetType() != typeof(AutoroutePartHandler));
       handlersExceptAutoRoute.Invoke(handler => handler.Removed(context), Logger);

    }
```

Tbh, I'm not really sure why this is necessary though. Before I added this new code, when I removed a draft content item with an autoroute part it seemed to result in there being no aliasrecords, but still having published autoroutepart records. So AutoRoutePartHandler.ProcessAlias() would think there was a duplicate published path and raise the conflict warning.